# Commute - IS the usage in the sentence right?

Tags: word-usage

Here is my sentence.

I have my own car that I use to travel to work.

If I say that I have my own commute, will it be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "commute" is the **journey** not the means of travel. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/commute) says

> NOUN
>   A regular journey of some distance to and from one's place of work.

So you could say

> I have a 40 minute commute.

but if you have you own car that you use to travel to work you can say

> I have my own transport.